# Show hover tooltip on td fullCalendar on left side - FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to display full calendar for my events, i need to display details on  fc-day hover as tooltip, this tooltip should be placed on left side with  fixed width and height,

As like below in image,

[image]

Please anyone provide me an idea to show tooltip as like in above image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FullCalendar events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/): `eventMouseover` and `eventMouveout` to show/hide a fixed positionned div.

You'll then need to do a little maths to place it exactly where you want.

I made a [little demo](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/owOxQL) for you, as a starter.

Comment: Patrice , Is is possible to keep height and width of fc-event to td height ?

Comment: Yes. You can get the event `.height()` using `$(jsevent.target).height()`.